# Accessing Data in a SQL Query

Tags: sql

tell me how to make a user access to data access,
There is a table with dialogs, and you need to build a query so that another user cannot see this data if he does not have access to this dialog.

I tried to do it but it didn't work

```
SELECT *
FROM NameDS INNER JOIN
DialogueListDS ON NameDS.UserID = DialogueListDS.UserID INNER JOIN
MessegesListDS ON DialogueListDS.DialogueID = MessegesListDS.DialogueID 
WHERE NameDS.UserID = '2B3F7596-DEC9-4CAF-A867-0127186CFC5C'
```

Comment: How do we know what "have access to this dialog" means?  You need to show all the table DDL,  explain what they are, sample data, expected output

Comment: Create a view. Grant SELECT on it to the other user.